# Hive SQL: How to find and flag occurrence within date range

Tags: sql, hive, duplicates, flags, find-occurrences

I have a set of data below and I need to find and flag who has called back within 5 days based on phone number and call date as below. How do I do this in hive? Thank you for your help.

```
PhoneNumber CallDate    Callback_Flag
    5713555841  5/6/2016    Yes
    5713555841  5/9/2016    No
    5713555841  5/19/2016   No
    5714390412  1/15/2016   Yes
    5714390412  1/19/2016   No
    5714390412  2/16/2016   No
    5714390412  3/24/2016   No
    5756379433  3/11/2016   Yes
    5756379433  3/16/2016   No
    5756379433  4/12/2016   No
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lead(calldate) over (partition by phonenumber order by calldate) > date_add(CallDate, 5)
             then 'Yes'
             else 'No'
        end)
from t;
```